# Spark 2.3.0 dataframe shows limited data

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark (python) to read data from csv file which contains 700,000 rows into spark DataFrame using the code shown below. When i display the records i can see only 2759 rows. Does a DataFrame have fixed size or am i missing something here ?

```
# create spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DailyItemSales").getOrCreate()

# get the raw data (RDD)
lines = spark.read\
  .format("csv")\
  .option("header", "true")\
  .load(filename)\
  .rdd

def parse_input(self, line):
    return Row(
        dish_name=line[1],
        section=line[3],
        family=line[4],
        subfamily=line[5],
        sale_date=line[6],
        quantity=self.get_value(line[7]),
        amount=self.get_value(line[8])
    )

def get_value(self, value):
    if value is None:
        return 0.0
    else:
        val = [float(x) for x in value.strip().split()]
        return next(iter(val))

# convert it to RDD of Row objects
sales = lines.map(self.parse_input)

# create dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(sales)

# display records (showing only 2759 records)
i = 1
for x in df.collect():
    print(i, x.dish_name, x.amount, x.family, x.quantity)
    i+=1
```

Comment: what is self.parse_input?

Comment: I just updated to include all the code

Comment: You do not need to convert to a RDD, you can perform the transformations on the dataframe `spark.read` gives you. Also, it would probably be easier to get the size with `count()`.

Comment: If i do df.count() it shows only 2759. My count of rows in the csv file is 79286

Comment: what is the count when you do lines.count()? and Shaido is correct that you don't need to convert to rdd and do the parsing and recreate dataframe. you can do the parsing in dataframe itself

Comment: lines.count() gives me 79283. The reason i'm converting it to rdd is because i want to get aggregate of a single column (without grouping).

Comment: so it is obvious that your parse_input function is removing the lines. So find out what is causing them to be removed. May be some of the lines don't have all the 8  elements. I guess your problem is solved. :) by the way what do you mean by `because i want to get aggregate of a single column (without grouping)`?